# arrays and listview for android (java)

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview

I am trying to show just the name of the player from the array into the list view. this is my code for that:

```
player_List.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Player>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataStore.getPlayers()));
```

im getting all the information from that array using this call. i am unsure how to just call the name.

this is the coding for my data store:

```
/**
 * This class is essentially a global library for the Scoresheet.
 * It provides methods through which the Players and Teams can be accessed
 * from any part of the application.
 * The saving/loading of application data will also be handled through this
 * class.
 * 
 * You can access this DataStore by calling:
 * DataStore dataStore = ((DataStore)getApplicationContext());
 * From any Activity
 */
public class DataStore extends Application {

    // Create ArrayLists to hold all our Player and Team objects
    private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    private ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    // File names for our internal storage:
    private String playerFileName = "players";
    private String teamFileName = "teams";

    /**
     * Add a Player object to the list of players.
     * @param p The Player object to add
     */
    public void addPlayer(Player p){
        this.players.add(p);

    }

    /**
     * Merge an ArrayList of Player objects with the current collection of Players
     * @param players ArrayList of Player objects to add to the collection
     */
    public void addPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players){
        Iterator<Player> it = players.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            this.players.add(it.next());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return an ArrayList of player objects containing all Players 
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers(){
        return this.players;
    }
```

and this is my player class:

```
public class Player implements Serializable{
    // Randomly generate serial ID
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7423594865734681292L;
    private static int ID = 0;  // Class variable
    public String name;
    private int id;

    public Player(String name) throws Exception{
        this.setId(ID);
        ID++;               // Increment class ID counter
        if (!this.setName(name))
            throw new Exception("Invalid Name");    // This is the only way to prevent the object being instantiated if it has an invalid name
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the players name as desired.
     * @param name
     * @return true on success, false on fail
     */
    public boolean setName(String name) {
        // Only update the name if we are actually given a string
        boolean success = false;
        name = name.trim();
        if (!name.equals("")){
            this.name = name;
            success = true;
        }
        return success;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CustomAdapter` and set in `getView(...) method`

Like,

```
Player player = getPlayers().get(position);
textview.setText(player.name)
```

see this example,,
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx

Comment: so basically you can create a player ie. enter the players name in a file. and i want to display the players name in the listview. so everytime the app is opened, all the players names which have previously been saved are all visible on the listview.

Comment: but not sure how to do this as the code i have places information like "group6.scoresheet.Player@44eec9c0"

Comment: `i dont know what is this("group6.scoresheet.Player@44eec9c0" ) ?`  but  make some efforts i give you path for solution and try to understand above two link example

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on android listview, but if it just uses `toString` to decide what to show, implement `toString` to just return `name`:

```
public String toString() { return name; }
```